# How to dynamically highlight text in ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I have a series of rows inside a ngFor.

```
<div *ngFor="let block of data;">
 <div class="class-row">
     <div class="left">A Label:</div>
     <div class="right">{{block.key1}}</div>
 </div>
<div class="class-row">
     <div class="left">Another Label:</div>
     <div class="right">{{block.key2}}</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

It turns out that for some rows I would like to highlight `{{block.key1}}` or `{{block.key2}}` based on some logic.

Is there a way of doing this in angular 4+?
I thought of calling a component function and passing it the `{{block.key1}}` or `{{block.key2}}`, something like

```
<div *ngFor="let block of data;">
 <div class="class-row">
     <div class="left">A Label:</div>
     <div [innerHTML]=highlight({{block.key1}}) class="right"></div>
 </div>
<div class="class-row">
     <div class="left">Another Label:</div>
     <div [innerHTML]=highlight({{block.key2}}" class="right"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

but this is probably not possible. 
Is there some way of changing the property of the text in the div dynamically?

Comment: If you are talking about styling the entire element, have you not looked at the [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) directive?

Comment: try using angular directives https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

Comment: @PatrickEvans I have looked at it but I am not sure how to pass {{block.key1}} to a component function that determines using complicated logic whether or not to highlight the element.

Comment: @CruelEngine For each row of the ngFor the decision whether to highlight the element or not needs some complicated logic to be done on the component not the template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can do it. I assume when you talk about hightlight you mean CSS. If so you better use ngClass. Here is an example of how you can do it.

```
<div *ngFor="let block of data;">
  <div class="class-row">
   <div class="left">A Label:</div>
   <div [ngClass]="[shouldHighlight(block.key2) ? 'highlight' : '']" class="right">{{block.key1}}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-row">
   <div class="left">Another Label:</div>
   <div [ngClass]="[shouldHighlight(block.key2) ? 'highlight' : '']" class="right">{{block.key2}}</div>
  </div>
</div>

 <!--You can also do it by this way -->

   <div *ngFor="let block of data;">
  <div class="class-row">
   <div class="left">A Label:</div>
   <div [class.highlight]="shouldHighlight(block.key1)" class="right">{{block.key1}}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-row">
   <div class="left">Another Label:</div>
   <div [class.highlight]="shouldHighlight(block.key2)" class="right">{{block.key2}}</div>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
  .highlight{
   /* Your CSS Here*/
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Suggestion: `[class.highlight]="condition"`.

Comment: Tks you @ConnorsFan

Comment: The problem is that the `condition` depends on the value of {{block.key1}}. So it needs to be some function of {{block.key1}} (and {{block.key2}}) in the component. I.e. condition=checkToHighlight({{block.key1}}) and condition=checkToHighlight({{block.key2}}). How can I do that?

Comment: You can write that checking it the template or Just have a function in your component that will return a reponse based or a parameter

Comment: @user35202 - `[class.highlight]="shouldHighlight(block.key1)"`.

Comment: Exactly @ConnorsFan.

Comment: @user35202 I updated the answer to ConnorsFan suggestion. Hope it will help

Answer (score 3):

The answer by @Ulrich is correct, but I would like to expand on an alternative, that is easily missed.

That is: you are assuming you *must* call a function inside the ngFor. Well, this is true if you choose not to preprocess the data.

What I would try to do is preprocess data when loading it:

```
this.data.forEach(block => {
  block.highlightKey1 = this.shouldHighlight(block.key1);
  block.highlightKey2 = this.shouldHighlight(block.key2);
}
```

If you can extend the model to include also this extra fields, everything is smoother:

```
<div *ngFor="let block of data;">
  <div class="class-row">
   <div class="left">A Label:</div>
   <div [ngClass]="[block.highlightKey1 ? 'highlight' : '']" class="right">{{block.key1}}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-row">
   <div class="left">Another Label:</div>
   <div [ngClass]="[block.highlightKey2 ? 'highlight' : '']" class="right">{{block.key2}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

At runtime this solution is going to perform slightly better, because no function call is going to be made during change detection, but only at load.

I find it cleaner too, because no "complex logic" is going to be invoked directly by the template.